# Increase height of the recyclerview after translation animation(using ObjectAnimator)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, objectanimator

What I have done is on button click I have hidden the barcode scanner i.e used the ObjectAnimator for "Y" translation. At the same time, recyclerview which is below barcode scanner will also be translated in "Y" direction using ObjectAnimator. Animation works great only problem that when recylcerview is "Y" translated, then below it has some white space and I am not able to make it fill whole space available. Check below code which I have used.

```
    //scannerLayout is barcode scanner and recycler view is list
    int height1 = scannerLayout.getHeight(); 
    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ofFloat(scannerLayout, "translationY", 0, -1 * (height1));

    objectAnimator.setDuration(1000);
    objectAnimator.start();

    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator1 = ofFloat(recyclerView, "y", barcodeInputBoxHeight); //barcodeInputBoxHeight - is height of edittext which is shown between toolbar and recyalerview 
    objectAnimator1.setDuration(1000);
    objectAnimator1.start();
    objectAnimator1.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            // here I am doing some other stuff
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

        }
    });
```

I tried setting new layout params for recyclerview onAnimationEnd but it didn't work.

Check the below video for exact problem 
[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Tfo_FD0F2bYW8zbTVnNU1FUHM/view)

Below is layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/content_pos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context=".modules.pos.POSActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/screenFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:elevation="6dp">

    <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView
        android:id="@+id/barcode_scanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonFlash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_flash"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_input_barcode"/>

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlInputBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCloseInputBox"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_close_input_box"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewSwitchKeyboard"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_keyboard"/>

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonCheckOut"
    android:layout_below="@+id/screenFrame"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonCheckOut"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:text="Checkout"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout `xml`?

Comment: @azizbekian check the added layout xml code.

Comment: Hey @pratik, can you share how you fixed it eventually?